# Change default search engine from in app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, mobile-safari

Is it possible to change the default search engine from inside my iOS app, so that instead of safari using Google it uses another engine?

If it is possible how do I do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer **NO** this isn't possible.